# How do you make an apache vhost that directs to an SMB network share?

Tags: linux, centos, virtualhost, server-message-block, apache2

I have an SMB file share going on my local network. I store all of my websites on this server. I have another server running CentOS hosting an Apache web server. How would you create a vhost that directs to the SMB share?

The SMB server's path is `smb://10.0.0.177/fms%20studios/Websites`.

This is what I currently have in my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin flyingmcsquid@gmail.com
ServerName tree.fmsds.xyz
ServerAlias www.tree.fmsds.xyz
DocumentRoot "smb://10.0.0.177/fms%20studios/Websites/"
<Directory  "smb://10.0.0.177/fms%20studios/Websites/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two distinct issues to solve your problem:

1. **Authentication**: supposing your Windows box is serving the "*fms studios*" network share, chances are high that such a share is "*protected*" so that remote access require a username/password pair;
2. **Access methods**: your Apache needs to know where the document-root of its virtualhost are located. Based on your question, you're "guessing" that an "smb://" prefix will let Apache knows/handle a remote-access to an SMB share.

Let's start addressing point 2. As you can see from [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) the "*DocumentRoot*" directive require a directory-path. This, commonly, is a "local" path defined within the filesystem of the local machine.

This is **not** a problem, for you, as it's perfectly possible to "mount" a remote SMB network share, "inside" our local file-system. Search for "linux smb mount" on your preferred search-engine or start investiganting from [here](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Mounting_samba_shares_from_a_unix_client). This will let your SMB share to be accessed under a path like `/mnt/server_win2012/fms%20studios`. You can think of this as the equivalent --as for windows world-- of accessing a network share with a drive-letter mapped to a remote path instead of accessing the UNC path (...starting with a `\\<something>`) directly from Explorer.

So, now you're able to let Apache asking for access to a network SMB share.

Let's step to point 1), "**Authentication**". As you can see in the "[Common mount.cifs options](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Mounting_samba_shares_from_a_unix_client#Common_mount.cifs_options)" section of already mentioned document, you can specify "*user=*" and "*pass=*" options while mounting the resource.

Please take some time to carefully think to the objective of such option, expecially related to other two additional options "*uid=*" and "*gid=*": the first two (*user=* and *pass=*) are used for remote authentication and, hence, should match some username defined **on the server**. The last couple (uid= and gid=) are used **on the client** to tell the local operating-system which will be the user and the group that will "own" the files, once mounted on the local filesystem and, hence, when they will be accessible to potentially *all* users defined locally (obviously, a totally different set wrt the server one -- at least in "common" scenarios). This can sounds a little tricky, in the beginning but... once you think to it, it will be clear quite soon :-)

As for you specific case, I guess you want to specify a "uid=" and "gid=" matching your local "httpd" user, so that Apache will be granted access to the remote resources.

I'm not digging further discussing Authentication issues and or the proper configuration to mount the SMB share automatically at boot as they are out of scope of the OP, so, please act by yourself. Nevertheless, I urge you to **act very carefully to avoid general write permission to the web-server**. More generally, be extremely carefull when granting access to local/network resources to an uid mapped to an Internet/Public service, like a web-server. Try to avoid such access and, if absolutely needed, grant it the absolutely minimimun permission set (I suggest: start with a **read-only** mount, or a read-write mount to a read-only network share and, if it's not enough... try to extend it later on...)

Comment: +1 In addition to mounting the SMB share there is also the `httpd_use_cifs` SELinux boolean to consider.

Comment: I was unable to mount the drive. What would the line that I put into /etc/fstab look like?

Comment: On one of my CentOS box, I've an `/etc/fstab` with a row similar to this: `//your.remote.win.box/sharename /storage cifs user,_netdev,uid=5001,gid=5001,rw,suid,username=damiano,password=guesswhat 0 0` where /storage is the mount point on the local filesystem (an empty directory, more or less)

Comment: When I go into the directory, is is empty. This is the whole line that I have: `UUID=faf01ac6-38c1-11e7-a919-92ebcb67fe33 //10.0.0.177/FMS%20Studios mnt/drives/FMS cifs user,_netdev,uid=abc,gid=123,rw,suid,username=abc,pass‌​word=123 0 0` In this example my username is abc and password is 123.

Comment: Your line is wrong. You should remove your first parameter (UUID=....) and should add a "/" in front of the `mnt/drives/FMS`. So, in the end, it should look like: `//10.0.0.177/FMS%20Studios /mnt/drives/FMS cifs user,_netdev,uid=abc,gid=123,rw,suid,username=abc,pass‌​word‌​=123 0 0`. Also, be sure that `/mnt/drives/FMS`is an existing directory within your linux filesystem.

P.S.: ...and be ready to deepen your knowledge about Linux as... you need to improve your "basic" skills :-)

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses! Anyway, the folder is still empty. Here is a video to show my setup. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e06JBJIrlMs

Comment: It looks like you have everything configured and... simply need to "mount" the remote share (in other words: to "connect" to it). From a root shell, launch the `mount /mnt/drives/FMS` command. You should get a prompt, without any output. By launching `df` both before and after such `mount /mnt/drives/FMS` command, you should be able to check if the mount has been successful or not. As for the second part of your video, it looks like your file-manager has no problem accessing the share. Actually, a `df` should show you where the file-manager mounted the network share.